# How to split sets and lists into rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

There are two columns that are sets/lists in the `pd.DataFrame` above. How can I efficiently separate columns like that such that each element of sets/lists sits in a single row indexed by the first column `user_id`.

For example:

```
user_id,category_id
4,2
4,3
4,4
...
5,3
5,8
...
```

Comment: Are all of them the same length?  Have you tried anything?

Comment: No. I think using iteration over each row like `.iterrow` would work, but that's probably not the most optimal approach to this kind of problem.

Comment: @JamesWong I normally wouldn't answer a question like this because you didn't provide any sample data (please don't include screen shots...) and didn't appear to make any effort yourself.  Please review [MCVE] and [ask].

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I should have included the code. I'm relatively new here, so I wasn't that familiar with the rules. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

Apply `pd.Series` to the `category_id` column to break the lists into separate columns, and then concatenate the result to the `user_id` columns.

Then just melt the result and sort the final values on `user_id` then `category_id` if required.

```
# Sample data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': range(2), 'category_id': [range(i, i + 3) for i in range(2)]})
# print(df)
# Output:
#    user_id category_id
# 0        0   [0, 1, 2]
# 1        1   [1, 2, 3]

# Result.
>>> (pd.melt(
         pd.concat([df['user_id'], df.category_id.apply(pd.Series)], axis=1), 
         id_vars='user_id', value_name='category_id')[['user_id', 'category_id']]
    .dropna(subset=['category_id'])  # Drop null categories.
    .sort_values(['user_id', 'category_id']))
# Output:
#    user_id  category_id
# 0        0            0
# 2        0            1
# 4        0            2
# 1        1            1
# 3        1            2
# 5        1            3
```

Comment: This works perfectly with equally sized sets/lists, but would create lots of NaNs when that isn't the case. I knew this was largely due to me not describing the question well enough. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Insert this before you sort the values: `.dropna(subset=['category_id'])`

Comment: Although a bit late, you may still want to edit your question to delete your screen shot, provide a small sample of data (e.g. `df = pd.DataFrame({ 'user_id': [0, 1], 'category_id': [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3]]})`), and include your initial attempt.  Also include your expected result given the sample data.